# c# mongodb import .csv file columns separated with "|" instead of comma

Tags: c#, mongodb, csv

I have a database (named "db").

I want to create a collection named "worker" using a file named "worker.csv". But in this file, columns(id, firstname, lastname) are separated with a "|" character instead of "," character.

I can import the content of this file using this command:

```
$ mongoimport -d db -c worker --type csv --file worker.csv --headerline
```

After this, I tried to get the number of workers named "Roberto" in my C# code.

```
var query = Query.Matches("FirstName", "Roberto");
var users = personCollection.Find(query);

Console.WriteLine(users.Count());
```

In the output, it says "0", but I know there are workers named Roberto.

I tried to see the content of the collection in "mongo.exe" using `db.worker.find()` command and it seems after the importing operation, a line (of worker.csv) looks like just one attribute instead of three(id, firstname, lastname). And I think it's a problem about the .csv file.

Is there a way to import from this file correctly?

Comment: Since my .csv files are very big, I need to develop a small application to modify them. It would be very good if I could find a way, but anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Then I'll definitely need to develop an application to modify the files. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you have Excel, you may try importing the file (and specify the `|` character) and resave with an actual comma.

Comment: If you're going to develop a small application to read the files, you could also just insert the data directly into MongoDB via the C# driver. The `mongoimport` step may not be saving you a lot of time, and you can have more control on data conversion if you import programatically.

Comment: Apparently not supported as of 2016, see [Import CSV with semicolon separator into MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39044556).