# Import CSV with semicolon separator into MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, csv

I've just try to import a CSV file (with semicolon ; separator) into a MongoDB database. I managed import with `mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file files.csv --headerline` but the result is not what I'm expecting.
The files have that form:

[image]

And I get the following result:

[image]

But I want to have something like:

```
{

   "_id": ObjectId("57b6e2654bf4a357b679305"),

   "geom_x_y" : "48.87792844925 , 2.3664591564",

   "circonfere" : "25.0",

   "adresse" : "PARIS 10E ARRDT - QUAI DE JEMMAPES",

   "hauteurnm" : "5.0",

   "espece" : "Acer platanoides",

   "varieteouc" : "'Schwedleri'",

   "dateplanta" : "31/12/2014"

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

mongoimport unfortunately doesn't allow you to specify your separator character. But it does work automatically with tabs as well as commas. If you know you won't ever have tabs in your input, you could replace all semicolons with tabs and that should then import correctly.

```
tr ";" "\t" < file.csv | mongoimport --type tsv ...
```

Comment: It is not a suitable solution for large files (mongoimport usually used for large files)

Comment: @IvanRave why do you say it is not suitable for large files? does tr load the whole file to memory ? or which is the reason?

Comment: I have just encountered this issue, and I have a perfect reason why this feature would be necessary to allow semi colons as delimiters:  because in my data, I have Python tuples that require the use of the comma; It would not be practical for me to recode the Python to output all data again with a new delimiter.

Comment: How does this solution work for Windows 10 PowerShell?  I am trying to implement your solution with my code that already works for mongoimport except for the semi-colon issue which corrupts the data in the MongoDB.  Because StackOverflow won't let me present the code prettily, I will just give you here the code that works for me; How would you add your code to this Windows PS code that works?

./mongoimport --type csv -d testdb -c testcollection --headerline --drop testfile.csv